# Ошибка при попытке использовать функцию из другого файла

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

Ссылка на архив с ботом, так как код большой - [*тык*](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/XxIfoHw9A9FOAw).

Объясняю ситуацию: в моём Discord-боте (в архиве он сильно урезан, но главная проблема остаётся), при попытке использовать функцию 'send_error' из файла 'utils' во время проверки выходит ошибка:

```
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'utils' has no attribute 'send_error' (most likely due to a circular import).
```

Ранее этой ошибки не было, пытался исправить её всеми способами - не смог.
*Чтобы использовать код из архива, впишите ваш токен в config.py*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Вашем проекте так называемый `Circular Import`.

При запуске `main.py` обращается к файлу `ban.py`, файл `ban.py` обращается к `utils.py`, `utils.py` обращается к `database_models.py`, который обращается к `main.py`, из-за чего образуется замкнутый круг: 
`main.py`->`ban.py`->`utils.py`->`database_models.py`->`main.py`


Чтобы всё работало как Вы хотите, достаточно просто в файле `database_models.py` стереть строчку

```
from main import bot
```

Она всё равно даже не используется :D